# Page redirection not working in codeigniter live server, but works in local server

Tags: codeigniter, redirect

Problem: Page cannot redirected to given page from controller in php code igniter. This task is working in local system server. But it not works in live server. Please help me.

Comment: provide more information. it is hard to tell why it is not working with above information.

Comment: I need to update some information in my mysql database. I added the details in view part and redirect page to  certain function in my controller.php, the controller execute the task insert the data into database ,after that i redirect the page to another view page. but it not redirecting. it gives some blank page with that controller url. this task is working in local server, but in live server not working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, you need to set your base_url correctly in config.php. 
Also check your .htaccess and change RewriteBase /(your base url here).
The second one was my problem.
Hope it helps!